# totally bounded and locally compact but not compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, locally-compact-groups

I am havig some trouble with topology. If you have a metric space which is totally bounded en locally compact, is it then compact? At first I though that this was not true. I tried some dicrete metric space and it failed. I tried to take the space of rational numbers with the interval [0,1] and it failed. 
So I could not find a good couterexample. I also could not prove that it is true... I still believe there is a counterexample. 
Any tips?

Comment: Compactness of a metric space is equivalent to being complete and totally bounded. Does local compactness imply completeness?

Comment: @Ian no, but local compactness plus metrisable does imply being completely metrisable. But you might need to change to an equivalent metric, see $(0,1)$, e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It's true, but once you change to the other metric, such a set is not totally bounded anymore. The topology itself can't "tell" which of completeness and total boundedness is the problem with the metric, but one or the other will be.

Answer (score 3):

I think $(0,1)$ is totally bounded, locally compact, and not compact.

Comment: Because it's an open set whose closure is compact.